# Schedule a JCL job to a specific time

Tags: jcl

I have a JCL JOB, which I need to be executed at a specific time periodically ( for example every day at a special time) and automatically. Is there any way to do so?
I found out some example of ´SCHEULE ´ and `STARTBY´ but I dont know how to add them to my JCL JOB.

Answer (score 0):

Use the // SCHEDULE statement

// SCHEDULE HOLDUNTIL=hh:mm:as

As an example.  See the IBM manual for more detail [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=reference-schedule-statement)

The statement is placed after the job are and before the first IF